# Convert LLaMA to ONNX

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to convert LLaMA to ONNX like so:

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

model_name = "C:/Projects/vicuna-13b-delta-v0"
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Make sure the model is in evaluation mode
model.eval()

# Set up a dummy input for tracing
input_str = "Once upon a time"
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(input_str, return_tensors="pt")

# Convert the model to ONNX
with torch.no_grad():
    symbolic_names = {0: "batch_size", 1: "seq_len"}
    torch.onnx.export(
        model,
        input_ids,
        "vicuna.onnx",
        input_names=["input_ids"],
        output_names=["output"],
        dynamic_axes={"input_ids": symbolic_names, "output": symbolic_names},
        opset_version=15,  # Use a suitable opset version, such as 12 or 13
    )
```

I get the error:

```
 python .\convert.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\vicuna-13b-delta-v0\convert.py", line 5, in <module>
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\auto_factory.py", line 441, in from_pretrained
    config, kwargs = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\configuration_auto.py", line 917, in from_pretrained
    config_class = CONFIG_MAPPING[config_dict["model_type"]]
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\configuration_auto.py", line 623, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'llama'
```

Is it possible to convert LLaMA to ONNX with huggingface transformers?

Comment: it looks to me like you need to use a newer (possibly development) version of huggingface transformers. however, there are more bumps later on. note that the optimum library supports exporting llama to onnx.

Answer (score 2):

Use huggingface optimum

**Step 1:** pip3 install optimum[exporters]

**Step 2:** command to convert pytorch llama2 to onnx model: `optimum-cli export onnx --model meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf ./onnx_model/`

**Reference:** https://huggingface.co/docs/optimum/exporters/onnx/usage_guides/export_a_model

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me. Just follow the below steps:

1. clone this repo for exporting model to onnx (https://github.com/tpoisonooo/llama.onnx.git) repo url: https://github.com/tpoisonooo/llama.onnx
2. follow STEP 1 as it is (if you already have a HF model, then you can move on to STEP2)
3. In STEP2, use this code for exporting your model to onnx.

```py
    from typing import List, Optional
    from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer
    import torch
    import sys
    
    PROMPT_DICT = {
        "prompt_input": (
            "Below is an instruction that describes a task, paired with an input that provides further context. "
            "Write a response that appropriately completes the request.\n\n"
            "### Instruction:\n{instruction}\n\n### Input:\n{input}\n\n### Response:"
        ),
        "prompt_no_input": (
            "Below is an instruction that describes a task. "
            "Write a response that appropriately completes the request.\n\n"
            "### Instruction:\n{instruction}\n\n### Response:"
        ),
    }
    PROMPT = PROMPT_DICT['prompt_no_input']
    
    CACHE_DIR = 'alpaca_out'
    
    class LLAMA():
        def __init__(self, outdir):
            self.device = 'cpu'
            self.model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(outdir, cache_dir=CACHE_DIR, local_files_only=True)
            self.model.to(self.device)
            print('model loaded!')
            self.tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(outdir, cache_dir=CACHE_DIR, local_files_only=True)
            print('tokenizer loaded!')
        def export(
                self,
                prompt: str = "bonjour",
                n: int = 1,
                total_tokens: int = 2000,
                temperature: float = 0.1, 
                top_p: float = 1.0,
                repetition_penalty: float = 1) -> List[str]:
    
            format_prompt = PROMPT.format_map({'instruction': prompt})
            _input = self.tokenizer(format_prompt, return_tensors="pt").input_ids.to(self.device)
            print('input ids created,now converting to onnx--------->')
            with torch.no_grad():
                symbolic_names = {0: "batch_size", 1: "seq_len"}
                torch.onnx.export(
                    self.model,
                    _input,
                    "llama-13b.onnx",
                    input_names=["input_ids"],
                    output_names=["output"],
                    dynamic_axes={"input_ids": symbolic_names, "output": symbolic_names},
                    opset_version=15,  # Use a suitable opset version, such as 12 or 13
                )
            # outputs = self.model.generate(
            #     _input,
            #     num_return_sequences=n,
            #     max_length=total_tokens,
            #     do_sample=True,
            #     temperature=temperature,
            #     top_p=top_p,
            #     top_k=40,
            #     repetition_penalty=repetition_penalty
            # )
            # print('generation done, decoding output---------->')
            # out = self.tokenizer.batch_decode(outputs, skip_special_tokens=True)
            # removing prompt b/c it's returned with every input 
            # out = [val.split('Response:')[1] for val in out]
            # print('Q: {} A: {}'.format(prompt, out))
            return None
    
    x = LLAMA(sys.argv[1])
    x.export()
```

in cli, run

```
$ python3 tools/export-onnx.py ${PATH_LLAMA_13B}
```

This will export your llama hf model to onnx.
I hope this helps.